# IBPlugin and paths to framework

Tags: cocoa, xcode, interface-builder, ibplugin

IBCocoaSimulator crashes when IB cannot find the framework, I assume that happens to you too. I can run IBCocoaSimulator without crash, when I manually copy my framework+ibplugin from the build dir into `/Users/username/Library/Frameworks`. I'm doing this with Finder, this is not optimal, but works.

I have searched for a smarter way and each solution (BWToolkit, BGHUDAppKit, KTUIKit) I have been looking at, **does things in much different ways**. One solution runs a sudo script that copies it to the system wide `/Library/Frameworks`. Another sets `@loader_path` and yet another uses `@executable_path`. I haven't had luck with any of them and because of the great differences it's hard to see the pattern.

I'm confused.

**How do you config you IBPlugin, so that you can embed it in your app?**

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Yay, solved it, after reading a [blog post by dribin](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/11/15/rpath/) about how to use @rpath, I figured out how to get it working with my IBPlugins. So copy using Finder is no longer needed.

What I did was:

1. For MySmallFramework set `Installation Directory` to `@rpath`
2. For MySmallPlugin set `Runpath Search Paths` to `@loader_path/../Frameworks`
3. For MySmallApp set `Runpath Search Paths` to `@loader_path/../Frameworks`

Nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be obvious to most of you, but neoneye's solution as posted in his "Update 1" requires your **plugin target** to have a **"copy framework files" build phase** with the given **framework assigned to**.

*(don't yet have enough points for direct commenting :( hence the answer post)*

Answer (score 1):

You can call this with external makefiles xcode project from ibplugin makefile like following example:

```
install_name_tool -change @loader_path/MyPluginName.framework/MyPluginName @loader_path/<absolute path or level to updirectory>/MyPluginName.framework/MyPluginName $(BINDIR)/MyPluginName.ibplugin/Contents/MacOS/MyPluginName
```